# Python constructor attibute missing

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to print dates in the following format:

```
23:59:59 Sunday
```

But all I get is this

```
23:59:59
```

This is my code:

```
    class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.value = start

    def advance(self):
        self.value = self.value + 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class CyclicCounter(Counter):

    def __init__(self, period, start=0):
        self.period = period
        Counter.__init__(self, start)

    def advance(self):
        self.value = (self.value + 1) % self.period

    def __str__(self):
        s = Counter.__str__(self)
        return (len(str(self.period - 1)) - len(s)) * '0' + s


class CascadeCounter(CyclicCounter):

    def __init__(self, next, period, start=0):

        CyclicCounter.__init__(self, period, start)
        self.next = next

    def advance(self):
        CyclicCounter.advance(self)
        if self.next and self.value == 0:
            self.next.advance()


class Clock(Counter):
    def __init__(self, h, m, s):
        super().__init__()
        self._h = CyclicCounter(24, h)
        self._m = CascadeCounter(self._h, 60, m)
        self._s = CascadeCounter(self._m, 60, s)

    def advance(self):
        self._s.advance()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(self._h, self._m, self._s)


class DayCounter(CyclicCounter):
    _days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
             'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    day = ''
    def __init__(self, day='Sunday'):
        self.day = CyclicCounter.__init__(self, day)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.day)


class DayClock(Clock):

    def __init__(self, h=0, m=0, s=0, day='Sunday'):
        super().__init__(h, m, s)
        self._d = DayCounter(day)

    def __str__(self):
        return Clock.__str__(self) + ' ' + str(self._d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import sleep

    clock = DayClock(23, 59, 45)
    threshold = 5
    while threshold > 0:
        print(str(clock) + "\n")
        sleep(1)
        clock.advance()
        threshold -= 1
```

As far as I can tell I do assign a value on the day attribute as well
so I would expect it to be printed to but it doesnt. Specifically, in
the main I create a DayClock, and I initialise the _d attribute with a
DayCounter instance of the class that takes as input the string value
of Sunday.

Comment: `DayClock` doesn't have its own `__str__` method, so it inherits the one from `Clock`. And the `Clock` method only prints `h:m:s`.

Comment: It's also notable that nothing in `DayClock` will ever cause the day of the week to advance. You probably need a lot more code to implement that class. Since we don't have the implementation of `CascadeCounter`, I'm not sure exactly how much (you might need to reimplement *all* of the contents of `Clock` so that when `_h` wraps around it advances the day).

Comment: I added the CascadeCounter class. I am not sure how to make the DayClock to advance though. After adding the missing __str__() method to DayClock, what I get is 23:59:46 None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DayClock` doesn't have a `__str__()` method that adds the day, it just inherits the method from `Clock`. It should call the inherited method and then concatenate the day name to that.

```
class DayClock(Clock):

    def __init__(self, h=0, m=0, s=0, day='Sunday'):
        super().__init__(h, m, s)
        self._d = DayCounter(day)

    def __str__(self):
        return Clock.__str__(self) + ' ' + str(self._d)
```

The `DayCounter` class also seems to have some serious problems. Shouldn't it use `_days.index(day)` to provide the `start()` argument to `CyclicCounter`? And the `__str__()` method should return a string from `_days`. I'm not going to try to fix all your bugs here, since the question was just about the `DayClock` class.

Comment: I am not sure how to make the DayClock to advance though. After adding the missing __str__() method to DayClock, what I get is 23:59:46 None
I have updated the code in the post to include the  the __str__() for DayClock

Comment: That's a completely different problem.

Comment: Did you fix the `__str__` method of `DayCounter`?

Comment: I have it returning     def __str__(self):  return str(self.day) , it prints none

Comment: So the problem must be with the CyclicCounter

Comment: I think that CyclicCounter would not work for the array of strings and that I need to create an extra CyclicDayCounter

Comment: `self.day = CyclicCounter.__init__(self, day)` is not right

Comment: The `__init__` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think you need to step back, slow down, and figure out each class one by one. You're trying to do too much at once and you're getting all confused.